# IF ELSE Statement always Returns True on First IF

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an IF ELSE statement that has several different ELSE IF statements to change a source image of a picture upon clicking a button.

A person will click on a body type button for a car, and when clicked it will display a background image within 3 existing buttons. Upon clicking one of those buttons an images' source should change.

Every time I run the code, it will only display the picture of my first IF statement. Any help with this would be appreciated. I apologize for the lack of knowledge with Javascript as I am self teaching myself.

### HTML

```
<div id="vehicleModelFrame">
        <button id="modelFrameButton1" type="button"></button>
        <button id="modelFrameButton2" type="button"></button>
        <button id="modelFrameButton3" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="selectTrimTitle">
        <h3>
            Vehicle Trim
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="vehicleTrimFrame">
        <div class="trimSelector">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Trim 1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Trim 2</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Trim 3</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Trim 4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane active">
                    <img id="carLogo1" src="" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
                <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane">
                    <img id="carLogo2" src="noimage.png" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
                <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
                    <img id="carLogo3" src="noimage.png" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
                <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane">
                    <img id="carLogo4" src="noimage.png" alt="carLogo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").addEventListener("click", function showTrim1(){
var carImg = document.getElementById("carLogo1");
var backImg = document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1");

if (document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage = "JeepWrangler.png") {

    carImg.src = "Jeep_Wrangler.png";

}else if (document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage = "BMW3.png") {

    carImg.src = "BMW3.png";

}
```

For the sake of learning Javascript I would like to keep possible solutions within the Javascript realm.

Comment: You're using the assignment operator `=` instead of a comparison operator (`==` or `===`).

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo.

Comment: @j08691: I'd call this small conceptual mistake rather than typo. Type would by `var hello = 3; console.log(helo)`.

Comment: @Linuxios You say potato, I say typo.

Comment: @Pointy I actually already tried that. When using the == operator, the picture won't display at all. Am I referencing the background image incorrectly?

Comment: @j08691: "You say potato, I say potypo, let's call the whole thing off..."

Comment: to check the background-image you should use "url(JeepWrangler.png)" or match(/JeepWrangler.png/);

Comment: @JeffBoynton: You might try logging (e.g. `console.log`) the value of `document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage` and seeing if it's of the form you expect in the first place.

Comment: Marking the post as a typo is hardly helpful. If you don't want to help out then don't post.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the equality operator, `==`, instead of the assignmet operator `=`.

Assignments return the value that was assigned, which in this case is a truthy string.

Answer (score 3):

You tested `if document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage = "JeepWrangler.png"`, but using a single equals means you assigned, rather than compared. Change the `=` to `===` (non-type coercing equality checking). In other cases, you might use `==` (type coercing equality), but `===` is usually more correct (type coercing equality behaves weirdly).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are assigning the value, rather than checking it:

```
backgroundImage = "JeepWrangler.png"
```

should be:

```
backgroundImage === "JeepWrangler.png"
```

Your `else if` statement will fail too:

```
else if (document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage = "BMW3.png")
```

should be:

```
else if (document.getElementById("modelFrameButton1").style.backgroundImage === "BMW3.png")
```